# OpenCV gets aways with assigning to a const reference?

Tags: c++, reference, opencv, constants

I stumbled upon this piece of code in the openCV source ( [cxoperations.hpp](https://code.ros.org/svn/opencv/tags/latest_tested_snapshot/opencv/include/opencv/cxoperations.hpp), line 1134, in the definition of the `Vector` class ):

```
Vector(const Vector& d, const Range& r)
{
    if( r == Range::all() )
        r = Range(0, d.size());

    // some more stuff...
}
```

Note that the `Vector` class has no data member called `r` (and indeed, the identifier `r` only occurs in one more place in the entire class definition, as a parameter in another method). So apparently, that right there is an assignment to a `const` reference.

I tried to reproduce a minimal example:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
  public:
    int _a;
    Foo(int a) : _a(a) {}
};

int main()
{
    Foo x(0);
    const Foo& y = x;
    printf("%d\n", y._a);
    y = Foo(3);
    printf("%d\n", y._a);
}
```

This, of course, fails to compile: g++ gives the error

```
test.cpp:15: error: passing `const Foo' as `this' argument of `Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&)' discards qualifiers
```

The only way I got it to work is by overriding `operator=` like this:

```
#include <iostream>

class Foo
{
  public:
    int _a;
    Foo(int a) : _a(a) {}
    Foo& operator=(Foo rhs) const
    {
        Foo& tmp = const_cast<Foo&>(*this);
        tmp._a = rhs._a;
        return const_cast<Foo&>(*this);
    }
};

int main()
{
    Foo x(0);
    const Foo& y = x;
    printf("%d\n", y._a);
    y = Foo(3);
    printf("%d\n", y._a);
}
```

This compiles, and prints "0 3" as expected. The problem here is that

1. anyone who writes code like that should have their hands cut off
2. in the openCV source above, there is no redefinition of `operator=` that takes `Range` parameters (`Range`-related functions are just above the definition of `Vector`, starting at line 1033)

Obviously I'm missing something, since the openCV source compiles. My question is, what is really going in in the `r = Range(0, d.size());` line that makes it legal?

Comment: We'll need to see the implementation (or at least declaration) of Range::operator= to answer your question...

Comment: There's a bunch of `Range::operator` functions defined just before the `Vector` class, though `operator=` isn't one of them. Presumably, it's the implicitly defined default operator.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I notice cv's `Vector` is a class template.  So if that class method was never instantiated, there was no compiler error.  My guess is that if you try

```
Vector<int> a;
Vector<int> b(a, Range::all());
```

you'll get a compiler error on that suspicious-looking line.  Then you can report it as a bug in the OpenCV source.

Answer (score 2):

My theory is that the offending code is never used and therefore never instantiated. Vector is a template, after all.

Consider this code:

```
template <class T>
class Vector
{
public:
   Vector()
   {
   }

   Vector(const Vector & x, const int & y)
   {
      y = 54;
   }
};
// template class Vector<float>;

void foo()
{
   Vector<float> v1;
//   Vector<float> v2(v1, 42);
}
```

GCC (version 4.5.1) accepts this, but complains as soon as you add that call to the second constructor or the eplicit template instantiation.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you submit it as a bug report [here](http://code.ros.org/trac/opencv), or post your message to the OpenCV newsgroup either at [Y!G](http://tech.groups.yahoo.com/group/OpenCV/) or to directly to the dev-list at "opencvlibrary-devel@lists.sourceforge.net".